# Ways to improve dynamic time warping word recognition system?

Tags: python, nlp, speech-recognition, dynamic-programming, speech-to-text

I recently got interested in speech recognition and have implemented a simple dynamic time warp system for word recognition for my own learning purpose. However after testing a bit I believe that I might made a mistake somewhere in the implementation, as the least distance value in traversing the dtw matrix does not accurately separate different word from each other. Here is the step I followed in the implementation.

1. Compute mfcc for two wav samples using https://github.com/jameslyons/python_speech_features (I will eventually replace it with my own mfcc algorithm)
2. Compute l2 norm for the top 13 mfcc in order.
3. Traverse through the dtw matrix and find the least distance.
4. Normalize the least distance by path length.

Below are my results

Comparing 39 samples of self recorded "on" vs "on" audio

```
35.5219789093
```

Comparing 60 samples of self recorded "on" vs "off" audio

```
35.6380793481
```

Comparing 25 samples of self recorded "turn on" vs "turn on" audio

```
36.5415412535
```

Comparing 28 samples of self recorded "turn on" vs "shut off" audio

```
31.1171968314
```

I tested couple more variations but find the result not promising.

I feel I am missing some crucial steps, but not sure what else I can improve on, any advice will be appreciated.

Thanks

Here is my code https://gist.github.com/anonymous/65a19bd17bdf0ad1d12d

To compare two files first create an instance of one file and use the compare function like following

```
kiwi = DTW(file_path, "kiwi")
kiwi_cost =  kiwi.compare(another_file_path)
```

Comment: What is the distance of the file to itself?

Comment: I tested a couple files, all of them is have a distance of 0.00 to oneself.

Comment: It is a very interesting question and application. Is this question still relevant or did you find a solution yourself? If so, please answer your own question, it would be highly beneficial to others.